# SUMIFS in Excel with cell reference

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to sum the values in sheet GLTB column D where the value in column A starts with 2.21 and the value in column E is equal to the date in the cell A1.  I tried this formula:

```
=SUMIFS(GLTB!$D$3:$D$26522,GLTB!$A$3:$A$26522,"2.21*",GLTB!$E$3:$E$26522,GLTB!$A$1)*-1
```

The problems:

1. The date in A1 doesn't appear anywhere else on the GLTB sheet, so I should get 0 for a sum, but I don't.  I get some number that doesn't correspond to anything I can find.
2. I can make all the values in column D where column A starts with 2.21 equal to 0 (or any other number) and it has no effect on the result of the formula.
3. I tried this formula based on answers to other questions:

   ```
   =SUMIFS(GLTB!$D$3:$D$26522,GLTB!$A$3:$A$26522,"2.21*",GLTB!$E$3:$E$26522,GLTB!"="&$A$1)*-1
   ```

This just changes the last criterion reference.  However, Excel gives me a formula error response.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are the values in column A actually *dates*? If so, understand that a date is stored as a long/numeric value and the actual *value* of the cell is **not** "2.21..." so using a string wildcard like `*` might not have the expected results for you...

Comment: is cell A1 part of the number for the rest of the numbers in column A?  is 2.21... part of a date or is it part of something else like a product code? Is the date in Column E and A1 stored as a string or a number as David pointed out.  one way to test this is =istext(A1).  if it return the value of True it is a string and not an Excel Date/time value stored as a number but formatted to look like something else.

Comment: We need more information, example data, in order to really be able to help you...

Answer (score 0):

This should get you a little closer:

```
=SUMIFS(GLTB!$D$3:$D$26522,GLTB!$A$3:$A$26522,">=2/21/16",GLTB!$E$3:$E$26522,GLTB!$A$1)*-1
```

This assumes that column A contains *date values* which are *formatted as string*.  If these values are not *date values*, then please give some example of what cell contents in column A.

Note: I'm not clear on why you're searching for "2.21*" so I used the `>=` operator. That can be changed, or we could add additional criteria to the `SumIfs` based on your needs.

Other things to be careful of:

Ensure that column E and cell A1 both contain the same *type* of data (either *date* formatted as string, **or** string data representing dates. If you have inconsistent data types, the equivalence test in your `Criteria2` (`GLTB!$E$3:$E$26522,GLTB!$A$1`) will not return the desired results.

Comment: I read that it was column E that was a date and Column A was a number that could be 2.21######.  But I may be wrong in my understanding.

Comment: @ScottCraner I think you're right... more example data is needed from OP... "value in column A starts with 2.21 " (presumably it is more than just a date, so of course his criteria is not being met...)

Comment: Yeah, to me the OP is putting the date he wants filtered in A1 but the data starts on row 3.  so column A is filled with numbers.

Answer (score 0):

To start with, you should format your data as table. To do this, use "Start > Format as table". This will also give you the option of giving your table a name, e.g. data. Basically this makes performing the following steps easier.

From then on, you don't need to reference with `GLTB!$A3:$A26522`anymore, but can use `data[ColumnA]`.

I'm assuming you have a column ValueA with something in there that might start with 2.21, then ValueD which you want to sum and DateE which should be equal to a certain date.

The formula you are looking for is not SUMIF, but the much better SUMPRODUCT, as this allows you to check multiple conditions.

The final formula will look like this:

`=SUMPRODUCT((data[DateE]=A1)*(LEFT(data[ValueA],4)="2.21")*data[ValueD])`

Now what does this do. SUMPRODUCT first builds a product and then sums that up. Let's assume the following values:

`A1 = 2016-03-01`

`DateE = 2016-03-01
ValueA = 2.213454
ValueD = 3`

The formula will then do the following:

`(2016-03-01=2016-03-01) is 1
("2.21" = "2.21) is 1
3 is 3`

`1*1*3 = 3`

Now if you change the date in A1, the value of your SUMPRODUCT cell should change accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

As a starter I recommend using Tables - it's much easier to read and maintain your data: `Insert-->Table`.

e.g.

Here I have "Table1", with the Date column formatted as a Short Date.

```
Name Date Quantity
Alpha 17-Mar-16 1
Beta 15-Feb-16 2
Charlie 11-Mar-16 3
Dog 11-Feb-16 4
Echo 9-Feb-16 4
Foo 6-Jan-16 5
```

Then in a separate row/cell, you can input a formula to sum the quantity column where the data is from 1st Feb onwards.

Here I've used a different date format, but Excel is fine with it.

Feb Onwards Total: 14 `=SUMIFS(Table1[Quantity],Table1[Date],">=01-Feb-16")`

Feb Only Total: 10 `=SUMIFS(Table1[Quantity],Table1[Date],">=01-Feb-16", Table1[Date],"<29-Feb-16")`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((INT(GLTB!$E$3:$E$26522)=INT(GLTB!$A$1))*(ROUNDDOWN(GLTB!$A$3:$A$26522,2)=2.21)*(GLTB!$D$3:$D$26522))
```

If this Returns and error, then one of two things:

1. your dates are not true dates but text that look like dates.
2. your have errors in your cells in some of the columns.